# Replace part of a string with an imported component

Tags: reactjs

We are presenting dynamic error messages which are listed in a locale file as a const. As a part of that string, I am placing text [Alert] which I would like to replace with an imported alert component (which displays a nice alert etc).

How do I go about replacing part of a string in a const with a react component?

Comment: Post relevant code, what you've tried so far, how it failed, error messages you got, etc. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Dont have any relevant code really - have just dabbled so far - was hoping to get some advice on which approach might be best...

Comment: Then you need to post elsewhere, SO is the wrong place for that. Asking a question here is the *last* thing you want to do, after having exhausted all other resources, and having spent hours trying to fix it yourself.

Comment: Perhaps something like...

`import {Alert] from 'Alert';

const message = (
   <p>This is a message<br />[Alert]<br />End of the message</p>
);

const replacedMessage = message.replace('[Alert]', <Alert />);
`

But, Im unsure....

Comment: I'll point you back at my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@KyLane , what about rendering the alert JSX inside the message Component as below ?

```
const renderAlert = () => (
  <h1>this is an alert Component</h1>
)

const AlertMessage = ({ renderAlert }) => (
  <div>
    <p>This is a message<br/>
      {renderAlert()}<br/>
      End of the message
    </p>
  </div>
);
```

this is a [link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/m7pp9zn879) so you could try it.

Comment: Thanks Tanik - I ended up doing this - and just passing new props through for my Alert. Thank you :)